# Selecting one value per row - awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file formatted like:

```
10.0.0.1        87.220.150.64   131
10.0.0.1        87.220.172.219  131
10.0.0.1        87.220.74.162   131
10.0.0.1        87.220.83.17    58
10.0.0.1        87.220.83.17    58
1.160.138.209   10.0.0.249      177
1.160.138.209   10.0.0.249      354
1.160.138.249   10.0.0.124      296
1.160.139.125   10.0.0.252      129
1.160.139.207   10.0.0.142      46
```

The first and the second columns are IP addresses and the third one is the bytes transferred between IPs. I have to count how many bytes each 10.something IP-address has sent or received.

I used following awk program to calculate how many bytes each IP had sent but I cant figure out how to edit it to also calculate the received bytes.

```
awk '{ a[$1 " " $2] += $3 } END { for (i in a) { print i " " a[i] } }' input.txt | sort -n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't distinguish between bytes sent and bytes received.

```
# bytes-txrx.awk -- print bytes sent or received by each 10.* ip address.
# Does not guard against overflow.
#
# Input file format:
# 10.0.0.1        87.220.150.64   131
# 10.0.0.1        87.220.172.219  131
# 10.0.0.1        87.220.74.162   131
# 10.0.0.1        87.220.83.17    58
# 10.0.0.1        87.220.83.17    58
# 1.160.138.209   10.0.0.249      177
# 1.160.138.209   10.0.0.249      354
# 1.160.138.249   10.0.0.124      296
# 1.160.139.125   10.0.0.252      129
# 1.160.139.207   10.0.0.142      46
#
$1 ~ /^10\./ {a[$1] += $3;}
$2 ~ /^10\./ {a[$2] += $3;}
END {
  for (key in a) {
    print key, a[key];
  }
}

$ awk -f test.awk test.dat
10.0.0.1 509
10.0.0.252 129
10.0.0.249 531
10.0.0.142 46
10.0.0.124 296
```

Comment: +1. I would be a bit more specific with the regexes: `$1 ~ /^10\./` and `$2 ~ /^10\./`

Answer (score 0):

Just sort by column 2 and you have it:

```
$ awk '{ a[$1 " " $2] += $3 } END { for (i in a) { print i " " a[i] } }' input.txt | sort -n -k 2
```

But your description does not match the calculation. You do not calculate how much an IP sends. You calculate how much is send from A to B. And the amount A sends it the same as B receives.